# my fetch gives me Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 Promise.then (async) (anonymous) @ App.js:5 invokePassiveEffectCreate

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch

I try to learn Js so i tried to do a simple api. The back (in node.js) load the meteo of a city, and i want to call this function on my front (react.js).

My Back works and give me this result:

```
{
    "temp": 290.77,
    "feels_like": 290.1,
    "temp_min": 290.49,
    "temp_max": 290.77,
    "pressure": 1019,
    "sea_level": 1019,
    "grnd_level": 1014,
    "humidity": 58,
    "temp_kf": 0.28
}
```

But when i try to call my back with the "fetch", it gives me

```
Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 Promise.then (async) (anonymous) @ App.js:5 invokePassiveEffectCreate
```

here is my call:

```
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http//localhost:8000/getmeteo')
    .then(res =>res.json())
    .then(res =>console.log(res))
  })
...
}
```

there is my serverfunction

```
app.get('/getmeteo', (req, res) => {
    let city = req.query.city;
    // var request = require('request');
    request(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=paris&appid=${apiKey}`,
        function(error, response, body) {
            let data = JSON.parse(body);
            if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                // res.send(data)
                res.send(data.list[0].main)
                // res.send(`The weather in your city "${city}" is ${data.list[0].weather[0].description}`);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Thanks for yours answers

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when your server returns HTML instead of JSON. If you look at the response from the server (using the browser developer tools), you will likely see HTML, for which the first character is `<`. If you try to parse HTML as JSON, you will get the error you are describing:

```
JSON.parse('<html>...'); // Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Even further, I expect that the HTML is an error page, likely a generic error page used by your server. You need to make sure the request is actually making it to your server and that your server is configured to handle it correctly.

**UPDATE:** It appears you have configured the route correctly for your server. The next thing is to make sure you have an error handler. Put this at the very end of your server code:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (res.headersSent) {
    return next(err)
  }
  res.status(500)
  res.json({ error: err })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i think my server gives me a json, how can i know what am i sending? I put my small function  on the top.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Your server code has serveral ways something can go wrong, and you are essentially swallowing the errors. See my updated answer.

Comment: Really thanks for yours answers, i did but that doesn't change anything (i put it between my function and my app.listen(8000 ....)

Comment: when i had a header, content type and accept, it gives me an other error

Comment: http://localhost:3000/http//localhost:8000/getmeteo 404 (Not found) but i have it